# Does GraalVM support SIMD / AutoVectorization at all or as well as jdk9+?

Tags: simd, java-9, graalvm

JDK 9 had some major performance improvements for SIMD / AutoVectorization that resulted in 2x to 4x improvements in many cases. Does Graal VM have the "same" improvements as jdk9 did for SIMD / Autovectorization support? (In fact, does it support SIMD / Autovectorization even at jdk8 level?)

Put another way, does the fact that Graal VM will eventually support jdk11 (according to this post: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/651) mean that it will automatically support SIMD / Autovectorization (and do so at least as well as jdk 11?)

Comment: Opinion: That link you've shared was a much better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraalVM EE does some auto-vectorization, it is rather different from C2's auto-vectorization so it may be that some cases that are covered by one are not covered by the other and vice versa.

C2 is HotSpot's JIT compiler that is replaced by the Graal compiler in GraalVM. As a result, a GraalVM based on JDK9+ would not change anything to GraalVM's auto-vectorization capabilities since the changes you mention for JDK9 were done on C2.

Comment: Excellent -- thank you. Do you know if there's a lay-person summary of Graal's autovectorization support (especially as it compares to JDK 9's C2 support?) In particular, is there a roadmap to make it "better" (I read somewhere -- can't recall where -- that Graal may have a better time at providing good SIMD support compared to C2 due to inherent advantages of the Graal architecture.) @Gilles D.